# Reducing Lag in Pi Camera

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, opencv, picamera

I found a code that can scan a barcode using the Raspberry Pi camera V2.1.

It works as expected and can detect a barcode when I present it to the camera. But if I move the camera around a little, there is a lag in the video. I tried increasing the camera. framerate but that doesn't do anything. Neither does change the resolution. Even if I remove the `dec()` function, the video still looks laggy.

How can I improve the camera framerate so it does not lag?

Also the code opens up a window where I can see the video. For now it is useful for debugging, but I was wondering how I could stop the Pi from opening the video window later on?

```
from ftplib import FTP
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import os, sys, cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import imutils, time

detectedBarcode = False

def dec(frame):
     global detectedBarcode
     x=decode(frame)
     for i in x:
        detectedBarcode = True 
        (x, y, w, h) = i.rect
 
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x, y),(x + w, y + h),(0, 0, 255),2)
        barcodeData = i.data.decode("utf-8")
        barcodeType = i.type
        print(barcodeData, type(barcodeData))
        #sys.exit()
        return(barcodeData,barcodeType,1)
     return('','',0)

def cameraReader():
   fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')

   camera=PiCamera()
   camera.resolution=(1296,730)
   camera.framerate = 30
   rawCapture=PiRGBArray(camera)
   cv2.namedWindow("QR Scanner",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

   global detectedBarcode
   avg = None
   for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture,format="bgr",use_video_port=False):
        image=frame.array
        cv2.line(image, (650, 0), (650, 1000), (0, 255,0), 2)
        x,y,p=dec(image)
        cv2.imshow("QR Scanner",image)
        if cv2.waitKey(2) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break
        rawCapture.truncate(0)

            #cap.release()
   cv2.destroyAllWindows()

cameraReader()
```